# how to get a raspberry pi to display the current time

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, display, lcd

how can I get a raspberry pi 16x2 charter display show the current time in the EST time zone using the "rpi_lcd" library, thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, you just need to use `datetime` and create a custom time [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and pass it to the `lcd.text` function. This code assumes that your circuit connection is fine.

```
import datetime
import pytz
from time import sleep
from rpi_lcd import LCD

lcd = LCD(width=16, rows=2)
tz = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")

while True:
    lcd.text(datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz).strftime(
        "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 1)  # for a 16x2 display
    sleep(1)
    lcd.clear()
```

Comment: when I do that I get this error                                                                                           "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))  # for a 16x2 display
TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'line'

Comment: Tnx for the tip, I forget to add the line number to show.